# Using statement, As vs =

Tags: vb.net

Is there a difference between using 'As' keyword and the '=' operator in vb.net?

Example:

```
Using aThing As New Thing()
    ...
End Using

' OR

Using aThing = New Thing()
    ...
End Using
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/865x40k4.aspx try these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no effective difference if you have `Option Infer On`.  If you have `Option Infer Off` then the first snippet will always result in a variable of type `Thing` while the second snippet will fail to compile with `Option Strict On` and result in a variable of type `Object` with `Option Strict Off`.

The first code snippet is explicit in its typing of the variable so it will be the type you specify regardless of what settings you have for `Option Strict` and `Option Infer`.  The second code snippet is not explicit about the type so that type must be determined implicitly by the compiler.  With `Option Infer On`, the type `Thing` can be inferred from the initialising statement.  With `Option Infer Off`, the type will default to `Object` and late-binding must be used, which is not allowed with `Option Strict On`.

It's worth noting that your original question isn't really valid because it's actually not a case of using `As` or `=`.  This:

```
Using aThing As New Thing()
```

is actually just a shorthand for this:

```
Using aThing As Thing = New Thing()
```

so you're actually using `=` either way and the choice is just whether or not to provide an `As` clause.  An `As` clause is required with `Option Strict On` unless you also have `Option Infer On` and the type can be inferred from the initialising statement.  If there is no initialising statement or the type of that statement is different to the type you want the variable to be then an `As` clause is required to tell the compiler the type of the variable that it cannot infer for itself.